# I am using laravel5.5 Ajax paging. When I click on page second, It will output data in JSON format

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `laravel5.5 Ajax` paging. I am the HTML part assembled in the controller. When I clicked on page second, I jumped to this method. How to make the compiled `HTML` code continue to display on the page?
After clicking on the second page, a string of `JSON` data is returned. This is a problem. How can we make the data on the second page continue to display in the original page?

> PHP

```
//Screen video, playback volume and key points.
public function accept（Request $ request）{
    $id=$_GET['id']; 
    $summer=$_GET['key'];
    $name=DB::table('vd_category')->where('address',$summer)->value('name');
    if($id=='1'){
$video=DB::table('vd_video_'.$summer)->orderBy('state','desc')->paginate(25);
        }else if($id=='2'){
            $video=DB::table('vd_video_'.$summer)->orderBy('thumbs','desc')- 
>paginate(25);
        }
        $data='';
        foreach($video as $list){
            $data.='<div class="col-md-1-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="padding:0 
5px;"><div class="movie-item">';
            $data.="<a style='position:relative;display:block;' title='$list- 
>video_name' target='_blank' href='details?id=$list->id&key =$summer'>";
            $data.="<img alt='$list->video_name' title='$list->video_name' 
 src=\"uploads/$list->image_address\" height=\"230px\" width='100%'>";
            $data.="<button class='bdtag'></button>";
            $data.="</a>";
            $data.="<div class=\"meta\"><div 
style=\"width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:20px;\">";
            $data.="<a href='/details?id='$list->id'&key='$summer' 
target='_blank' title='$list->video_name' class=\"movie-name\">$list- 
>video_name</a>";
            $data.="<span class=\"otherinfo\"> 5.0分</span></div><div 
class=\"otherinfo\">类型：$name</div></div></div></div>";
        }
        $datav['1']=$data;
        $datav['2']="<div>"."{$video->appends(['id' => 
 $id,'key'=>$summer,'name'=>'page'])->links()}"."</div>";
        return json_encode($datav);
}
```

> HTML

```
<div id="data">
    @foreach($video as $list)
        <div class="col-md-1-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="padding:0 5px;">
            <div class="movie-item">
                <a style="position:relative;display:block;" title="{{$list- 
     >video_name}}" target="_blank" href="/details?id={{$list->id}}&key= 
    {{$status}}">
                     <img alt="{{$list->video_name}}" title="{{$list- 
       >video_name}}" src="{{asset('uploads')}}/{{$list->image_address}}" 
    height="230" 
    width="100%">
                    <button class="bdtag"></button>
                </a>
                <div class="meta">
                    <div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:20px;"><a 
    href="/details?id={{$list->id}}&key={{$status}}" target="_blank" title=" 
    {{$list- 
    >video_name}}" class="movie-name">{{$list->video_name}}</a><span 
     class="otherinfo"> 5.0分</span></div>
                    <div class="otherinfo">类型：{{$namme}}</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div id="datav" style="background:#FFF;padding-left:15px;">
{{$video->appends(['id' => $page,'name'=>'page'])->links()}}
</div>
```

> JavaScript

```
<select name=""  required id="where_id" style="float: right;padding- 
    left:10px;border-left:8px;width: 90px;height: 30px;">
    <option value="">Click screening</option>
    <option value="1">Sort by play volume</option>
    <option value="2">Ranking by points</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="summer" value="{{$status}}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    $("#where_id").change(function () {
    var id=$("#where_id").val();
    var summer=$("#summer").val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"accept",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{id:id,key:summer},
        success:function (event){
            $("#data").html(event[1]);
            $("#datav").html(event[2]);
        }
      });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you realise that it is a community everyone speaks English?

Comment: It's alright now

Comment: Who knows?Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
  It has been solved.js has been modified.
That is, the parameters carried by the URL through the Ajax request to the 
back-end again, and then the back-end returned JSON data inserted into the 
specified location again, probably this is the solution, my English is not 
very good, please forgive me.


<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
 });
 $("#where_id").change(function () {
    fun();
 });
 function fun() {
    var id=$("#where_id").val();
    var summer=$("#summer").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"accept",
        dataType:'json',
        data:{id:id,key:summer},
        success:function (event){
            $("#data").html(event[1]);
            $("#datav").html(event[2]);
            pagedata();
        }
    });
     }
        function pagedata(){
    $(".page-item a").click(function (){
        var href=this.href;
        this.href="javascript:void(0);";
        var id=getQueryVariable('page',href);
        var key=getQueryVariable('key',href);
        var page=getQueryVariable('page',href);
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "accept",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: id, key: key,page:page},
            success:function (event){
                $("#data").html(event[1]);
                $("#datav").html(event[2]);
                pagedata();
            }
        })
    })
    }
   // Intercept the parameter values carried by URL, such as page parameters 
    //and some custom parameters.
     function getQueryVariable(name,url) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(^|&)' + name + '=([^&]*)(&|$)', 'i');
        var data=url.slice(url.indexOf('?'));
        var r =data.substr(1).match(reg);
        if (r != null) {
            return unescape(r[2]);
        }
        return null;
    }
  </script>
```